# Why does Coop Mode not work for my Assembly?

Tags: space-engineers

I have three assemblers currently on my station. Two are marked for Coop Mode and named Slave I and Slave II. I only issue build orders to the Master Assembler. But the other 2 assemblers do not get any build orders. I can issue direct orders to the slave assemblers though.

[image: Master Screenshot]
[image: Slave I]
[image: Slave II]

It starts working when I set my entire base to be owned by nobody though. It won't work when everything is owned by me.

Is there a way to get my assemblers working while the base is owned by me without tearing down/rebuilding the whole base? All Items in the base are currently owned by me and shared with the faction (Screenshot says differently, but I changed it), I double checked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the current build. If one wants to work around it, set the owner to yourself and share the assemblers with **everyone**. This makes them work in coop mode again. Another solution is to build them in a way that does not require the use of any conveyors, including the connection to any sort of container.

Comment: So the bug is in because of the conveyors, not the assemblers?

Comment: @Philipp Yes. If you use conveyors with your assemblers, the coop mode does not work when shared with faction or not shared. If you build them next to each others conveyor connectors and connect them this way, it works.